# Wrong cipher text length when using 3DESede with PKS5 padding of javax.crypto

Tags: java, android, encryption, 3des

I am using the following code in my android application to encrypt a string in [Triple DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) using the *Encrypted Code Book* (ECB) mode with three independent keys (aka *3DESede*), which are provided as a 24 byte sized key array. Therefore I use the [Java Crypto API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html). This works pretty well, but if I encrypt an eight character string I get a 16 byte cipher text, which should not happen as 3DES operates on chunks of 64 bit (resp. 8 byte). Same holds for the [PKCS5 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) as this also operates on chunks of 64 bit. So my question is what causes this problem?

```
private static byte[] encryptText(String plaintext, byte[] keyBytes) throws Exception {
    // Get plaintext as ASCII byte array
    final byte[] plainBytes;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        plainBytes = plaintext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    } else {
        plainBytes = plaintext.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    }

    // Generate triple DES key from byte array
    final DESedeKeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

    // Setup the cipher
    final Cipher c3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c3des.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    // Return ciphertext
    return c3des.doFinal(plainBytes);
}
```

Comment: 1. It is best not to use 3DES in new code, AES is the current symmetric encryption standard. 2. Do not use ECB mode, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin. 

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret. 3. Encryption is easy, making the usage secure is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PKCS5Padding** adds 1-8 bytes of padding when used with DES. If you encrypt 8 bytes you will get 8 additional bytes of padding to get to an even number of blocks.

If you used `Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding")` and encrypted 8 bytes, you will get 8 bytes of cipher text.

Answer (score 1):

When PKCS#5 padding is used it must always add padding otherwise on decryption there would be no way to determine if padding was added. So, even if the input data is an exact multiple of the block size padding must be added and that will be 8 bytes.

See [PKCS padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7):

> If the original data is an integer multiple of N bytes, then an extra block of bytes with value N is added. This is necessary so the deciphering algorithm can determine with certainty whether the last byte of the last block is a pad byte indicating the number of padding bytes added or part of the plaintext message. Consider a plaintext message that is an integer multiple of N bytes with the last byte of plaintext being 01. With no additional information, the deciphering algorithm will not be able to determine whether the last byte is a plaintext byte or a pad byte. However, by adding N bytes each of value N after the 01 plaintext byte, the deciphering algorithm can always treat the last byte as a pad byte and strip the appropriate number of pad bytes off the end of the ciphertext; said number of bytes to be stripped based on the value of the last byte.
>
> PKCS#5 padding is identical to PKCS#7 padding, except that it has only been defined for block ciphers that use a 64-bit (8 byte) block size. In practice the two can be used interchangeably.